# How to Create New file every time with new output

Tags: bash, shell, unix, unix-timestamp

I have shell Script which is currently running in every 5 minutes (i configured in crontab) and sending all the output in same file.

- I want that in every 5 minute(when cronjob will exexute) the output of the script should be send in new file with "current_date_year_time.csv"

Current Script

```
#!/bin/sh
ipath=/usr/local/nextone/bin
ifile=/var/tmp/EndpointUsage.csv
"$ipath"/cli iedge list | awk '
BEGIN { print "------------------------------------";
    printf "|%-17s|%-16s|\n","Registration ID", "Ongoing Calls"
  }
/Registration ID/ { id = $3; next }
/Ongoing Calls/ {print "------------------------------------"; printf  "|%-17s|%-16s|\n",id,$3 }
END{
print "------------------------------------";
}'>> "$ifile"
```

Current output is coming like as below.

```
EndpointUsage.csv

I want something like below.

EndpointUsage_09:55-Am_09_05_2015.csv
EndpointUsage_10.00-Am_09_05_2015.csv
EndpointUsage_10:05-Am_09_05_2015.csv
```

Can anyone please help me on this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I edited your script to suite your needs, see below:

```
#!/bin/sh
ipath=/usr/local/nextone/bin
date=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
ifile=EndpointUsage$date.csv
"$ipath"/cli iedge list | awk '
BEGIN { print "------------------------------------";
    printf "|%-17s|%-16s|\n","Registration ID", "Ongoing Calls"
  }
/Registration ID/ { id = $3; next }
/Ongoing Calls/ {print "------------------------------------"; printf      "|%-17s|%-16s|\n",id,$3 }
END{
print "------------------------------------";
}'>> "$ifile"
```

The additions I made was

```
date=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
ifile=EndpointUsage$date.csv
```

[Format the timestamp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the ifile= line to something like this (use 'date' to format the path/file you want to write the output into)

```
ifile="$(date '+/var/tmp/EndpointUsage_%I:%M-%p_%d_%m_%Y.csv')"
```

The man (or info) page for date has a list of all the placeholders you can use.
http://linux.die.net/man/1/date